# Key names narrow to properties names of other object in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I want to do my code better. I have this one:

```js
interface MyInterface {
  propertyOne: string;
  propertyTwo: string;
}

type MyProps = 'propertyOne' | 'propertyTwo'; // repeating names !!!
```

I need get type included name of `MyInterface` properties. Exists something like?:

```js
type MyProps = Props<MyInterface>; // incorrect !!!
```

because I need to declaration narrow key names in other object:

```js
let MyObject: { [key in MyProps]: SomeOtherInterface }; // I want to do better (without MyProps)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution is to use `Record` and `keyof`:

```
let myObject: Record<keyof MyInterface, SomeOtherInterface>;
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you seeking to `keyof` keyword?

```js
interface MyInterface {
  propertyOne: string;
  propertyTwo: string;
}

type Keys<T extends object> = keyof T;
type MyProps = Keys<MyInterface > ; // no repeating repeating names !!!
let MyObject: { [key in MyProps ]: string } = {
    propertyOne: 'test',
    propertyTwo: 'test'
}
```

[Link to playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8CS5rycgbwFgAoZZABygHsLox0B5ECALmQGcwpQBzAblLkqteugAqAd2rsuPEANIBfUqQZ1kAaQjoOAHnHIIAD0ggAJh2TUARgCsICMAD5kAXmQBrHdRjJxgiTqKBgACjQUVh7aunoY2JCwiCiu-MgA9OnIINTIUBB0cGB8eQUQRSUgcAC2EFYAhI2kADYQYGhM9o5g7ATIANre6MigHeG0VgC6stwlSu6EQuSUEWLMbMgA5JBcmwA0S8KrUAxSMls7YJvKQA)